# Fastest way to move image pixels between Blender and GPU memory?

Tags: python, image, gpu

I want to `cudaMemcpy` directly into `bpy.data.images["my_image"].pixels`, is that possible?

Right now I am doing this, and it is not as fast as I would like..

```py
# upload image to a numpy array
np_data = numpy.zeros((my_image.size), dtype=numpy.float32)

pixels_list = list(my_image.pixels)

for i in range(0, len(my_image.pixels)):
    np_data[i] = pixels_list[i]

# do stuff on GPU
GPUkernel.apply_filter(ctypes.c_void_p(np_data.ctypes.data))

# move data back to host from GPU into np_data
# code here..

# update image in blender
my_image.pixels = np_data.tolist()
```